# MySQL: Get average for values that correspond to a certain a ID

Tags: mysql, function

I am trying to create a table that contains the average review for every car model in a separate table. The output should look something like:

| car_model_id | avg_stars |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 |
| ... | ... |

My approach to get this table is to use a function that calculates the average for every car_id that it is given. I started with the following but it yields an error because this format returns a table not an int. Also, the getAverage() function is not implemented correctly in the create table statement.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getAverage(car_id_input int) RETURNS INT  
BEGIN
    SELECT AVG ( `car_id` )  /* To Fix */
    FROM `car_user_reviews`
    WHERE car_id = car_id_input;
END$$


CREATE TABLE `car_overall_stars` (
    `car_id` INT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`car_id`),
    getAverage(car_id) AS `average_stars` FROM `car_user_reviews`, /* To Fix */
    FOREIGN KEY (`actor_id`) REFERENCES `actor` (`actor_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

);

Any clues on how I can make this work? or any other approaches to take?

Using latest version of MySQL server.

Comment: You can create a view first such as `create view car_rating_avg as select car_id, avg(review) from car_user_reviews group by car_id`. Then, try to use this view and see if it is fast enough. If it is, use it as-is. Otherwise, create a new table and do `truncate table newtable; insert into newtable select * from car_rating_avg;` every night to populate the newtable with fresh average ratings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @zedfoxus in the comment

```
create view car_rating_avg as select car_id, avg(review) from car_user_reviews group by car_id.
```